# Can we get our personal voting data displayed on the Questions lists?

Tags: feature-request, voting, question-lists

There's been several times where I have been surfing the site, and noticed a question that I am not sure I've checked. Even if I've checked the question before, I can't recall off-hand whether or not I've voted on it or its answer.

Is there a way we can have our personal voting history reflected to some degree or another, in the Questions listing? For example, could there be an indicator as to whether or not we have already voted (up or down) on a question, and perhaps maybe an additional indicator as to whether we've up-voted any of its answers?

It would be very convenient to have some of this data available up-front, without actually having to view the question again.

Comment: What problem does this solve? Convenient, okay. But why?

Comment: @jon To repeat my comment from below, I'm systematically working through the archives, voting and answering. It would be really useful to be able to have a search filter which, combined with Votes:X would allow me to vote on lowest-ranked questions first. It's certainly a niche search criteria, but for those going through the archives, trying for necromancy, it's quite handy.

Comment: @JonSeigel I think it perhaps not that we're trying for Necromancy (directly) just that if an old low vote question is out there it'd be good for us to see if we've already voted/tried to help out.

Comment: I'm sure the major problem with this is the additional server load and potential performance hit. That information isn't exactly available to the minimalistic view in a list. This would require checking the votes table for a vote from you on that questiom for *every question* in the list. That doesn't sound too feasible to me.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about suggesting this recently.
Nothing related to badges, but sometimes when I'm busy on other things I view only new questions on the first page, then (hours) later I might have more time and go further back than just first page. But with there now being a lot of new questions on the first page, going through the subsequent pages of questions I do hit the ones I've already seen previously.

While the *visited* link CSS code sorts it out to a degree and shows me which links I've clicked on, it would be useful to know at a glance on the list of questions which questions (and answers) I've voted on.

However having said that, I'm not sure how useful this would be.
The room on the question and answer up and downvote box is quite limited, so any additional info provided would also be limited, thus potentially reducing any benefit gained.

EG:
[image]

You'd only need one on question - up or down - as obviously can only vote one way there.
Then on answer, there could be up, down, or both. But this would mean you've voted on *any* answers in this question.

So it's not giving you a lot of info on the questions page due to limited data, but might be useful.

You can see from the picture I made above, it does look quite neat, however not sure how many people would care about this.

In fact, it would be *much* more useful to see if *I've* answered on a given question, than it would to know if I've voted on a given question or it's answers.
I'm sure (speculation) that more users would prefer to know when they've answered than if they've voted.
Both could be done, as per following image, but also see the tick which on it's own without if I've voted or not would be quite useful...

[image]

The tick would indicate you have given an answer in the question.

Comment: This design doesn't work on many sites though. And the relevant information (the numbers) is getting lost there now :-/ You often have thirty-something votes (even a hundred-something) and twenty-something answers -- how's that all going to fit in?