# Indicate whether you voted (up/down), in main list

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, up-votes, question-lists

The main Q & A listings do not show *whether I have voted* on a given item, and if so, *whether up or down*.  This feature request is to do that: show whether ***I*** have voted on a question or answer already, and if so, whether I voted up or down.

(I don't think this is a duplicate -- AFAICT, other, related questions concern only reordering or filtering to show questions or answers that I have voted on.)

The main Q & A listings currently show the following:

- The number of votes and the number of answers, for each question (or the number of votes, for each answer).
- Whether there is an accepted answer.
- Whether I have visited a given item listed (though I'm not sure whether that is persistent or just a browser-visitation thing).

On the page for an individual question, we show the user's up/down vote info by highlighting the up/down arrow.  This could be done on the main listing as well.

This should be *independent of filtering and ordering*.  Being able to see which things I have voted on is independent of being able to filter which things are listed and what order they appear in.

IMO, this would provide a big benefit.  Just as indicating whether I have visited a given question or answer helps me avoid clicking it again later, this would help me determine which of them I might want to visit or revisit in order to provide an answer.

Comment: The indication of whether you've previously visited a question is a browser setting, not anything to do with SO.

Comment: You want this on the question listings?  I imagine that's a pretty expensive query.

Comment: @MattDMo -- Yes, I suspected that.  (It is nevertheless helpful, and for similar reasons to what I am requesting.)

Comment: @TheGrinch -- Yes, I too imagined it might be, but I don't know that.  Perhaps it could be done only for the currently viewed page, which does not hold that many entries.  And perhaps it could be a user choice to turn it on/off.  Maybe someone implementation-savvy will chime in.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72373/can-we-get-our-personal-voting-data-displayed-on-the-questions-lists/211690#211690

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the same suggestion.  Or almost the same.  I wouldn't limit this to a list of questions (with or without their answers).  It should also be for lists that show only answers (e.g. `is:answer`).